Continuing Page number in roman from dedication page in report
I would like to start my page numbering from the dedication page in roman. However, the page number is shown only in dedication page and it is not continuing in the next pages.
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{comment}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=28mm,bmargin=29mm,lmargin=32mm,rmargin=20mm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.8}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\onehalfspacing

\newcommand*\wrapletters[1]{\wr@pletters#1\@nil}
\def\wr@pletters#1#2\@nil{#1\allowbreak\if&#2&\else\wr@pletters#2\@nil\fi}

\usepackage{hyperref}  %to make hyper reference to TOC
\usepackage{blindtext}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gb}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\hfuzz=30pt
\vfuzz=30pt
\hbadness=\maxdimen
\vbadness=\maxdimen
\lstset{
%language=[LaTex]TeX,
keywordstyle=\small\bf\color{blue},
commentstyle=\small\color{gb},
stringstyle=\small\color{red},
}

\makeatletter
\makeatother

%\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    %\thispagestyle{epty}
    {\centering
    \fontsize{22}{26}\selectfont \textbf{SMART WATER LEVEL MONITORING }\\
    \vspace{1cm}
    \fontsize{18}{21}\selectfont \textit{A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for}\\
    \fontsize{18}{21}\selectfont \textit{the award of the degree of}\\
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    \fontsize{18}{21}\selectfont \textbf{Bachelor of Technology}\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \fontsize{18}{21}\selectfont \textit{By}\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}
       \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l l}
            \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont \textbf{N. Deven} & 2101\\
            \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont \textbf{Nh. Diya} & 2102\\
            \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont \textbf{Luwang} & 2104\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{18}{21}\selectfont \textit{Under the Guidance of}\\
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont \textbf{Guide}\\
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    {\centering {\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{ballervsnoob.png}}\par}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont \textbf{DEPT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE \& ENGINEERING}\\
    \vspace{0.1cm}
    \begin{center}
        \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont \textbf{TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY}\\
        %\bf{TAKYELPAT (IMPHAL) -795004}\\
        %\bf{MANIPUR, INDIA}\\
        \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont \textbf{OCTOBER, 2024}\\
    \end{center}}
\end{titlepage}


\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman} 
\setcounter{page}{1}
%Dedication Page

\vspace*{0.6cm}

\begin{center}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\pagenumbering{roman} 
\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont
\textbf{DEDICATION}\\[0.5cm]
\end{center}

\vspace{1cm}
{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont
\noindent
We dedicate this project report to our families, friends, and mentors who have been a constant source of inspiration and support throughout our academic journey. Their unwavering encouragement and belief in our abilities have driven us to explore new ideas and achieve our goals.\\ 

\noindent
We would also like to extend our heartfelt gratitude to our esteemed institution and faculty members, whose guidance and knowledge have shaped us into better engineers. This project, Smart Water Level Monitoring  is the culmination of our collective efforts, driven by our passion for technological innovation and problem-solving.\\

\noindent
Lastly, we dedicate this project to all those who strive to make the world a better and more sustainable place through the application of smart technologies.\\

\noindent
\textit{This work represents our commitment to contributing to a smarter future, and we hope it serves as a stepping stone for future innovations in the field of IoT and water resource management.}}

\pagebreak

%BONAFIDE CERTIFICATE
\setlength{\headheight}{2.5cm} % Adjust the height for the header to prevent overlap
\setlength{\headsep}{1.5cm}    % Adjust the separation between header and body

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% Header with logo and title
\fancyhead[L]{
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{ballervsnoob.png} 
}
\fancyhead[C]{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \textbf{\large TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY}\\
    \end{minipage}
}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
    \fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont
    \bf{BONAFIDE CERTIFICATE}\\[0.5cm]
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\noindent
\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont
\blindtext[1]
\vspace{2cm}
\noindent
\begin{flushright}
    \begin{minipage}{7cm}
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{Head of Department}\\
            
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
\end{flushright}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{flushleft}
Date: \today
\end{flushleft}
\pagebreak

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty} % No header or footer on this page
\begin{center}
    \fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont
    \bf{DECLARATION}\\[0.5cm]
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\noindent
{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont
\blindtext[1]
\vspace{2cm}
\noindent
\begin{flushright}
    \begin{minipage}{7cm}
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{N. Diya}\\
            Reg. No. 2101\\
            Dept. of Computer Science and Engineering
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{flushleft}
Date: \today\\
Place: Thanga
\end{flushleft}}
\pagebreak
\end{document} 


please always format code you post by highlighting it and using the code button or ctrl+k (on linux in kde - possibly some other key on other systems).

@roshni  Better always to use example-image-a.jpg etc when you posting a question as we dont have your specific images. Your fancy  does not specify a footer, so hence you get the problem. Use \thispagestyle  to place a heading on a single page and \pagestyle to let it continue on following pages. Also \centering  does not take an argument.  Define your fancy in the preamble only. Please modify and come back if this does not fix the issues.

@roshni  For a thesis you better off with book  check also your usage of \newpage etc. When you open the book the larger margin must be on the outside.
